# oci8 extention not working in php-5.4.3

Tags: php, oracle11g, php-extension, oci8

I'm using wampserver and i want to use the oci8 to connect to the oracle database 
i enabled the oci8 but when ever i see my phpinfo(); it's not there 
can any one tell me what's going on. i have been searching everywhere for hours but i couldn't find a solution at all. i'm using WampServer Version 2.2 Apache 2.4.2 – PHP 5.4.3 and oracle 11g.
every time i execute:

```
<?php

if ($conn = oci_connect('sys as sysdba', '12345', '//localhost/orcl'))
{
    print 'Successfully connected to Oracle Database!';     
}
else
{
     $errmsg = oci_error();
     print 'Oracle connection failed' . $errmsg['message'];
}
?>
```

it shows this error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function OCILogon() in C:\wamp\www\IDS\Index.php on line 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded a different php and Apache version
instead of `Apache 2.4.2 – PHP 5.4.3` now i'm using `Apache 2.2.2 – PHP 5.2.6`
from [wampserver-Addons - Add versions of Apache, MySQL et PHP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/#download-wrapper) 
and i reemoved the `";"` semicolon from the `php.ini` file at the oci8 line

it was like this:

```
;extension=php_oci8.dll
```

i changed it to:

```
extension=php_oci8.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

First enable your wampserver extension php_oci8 and php_oci8_11g. then please try below code.

In this please put database name instead of SID.

```
$c = oci_connect($userName, $password, "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =$serverName)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=$databaseName)))");
```

After using this connection string you can access all database function like
OCIParse
OCIExecute

Comment: I actually tried that, but the problem i guess it's in the oci8 it self. It doesn't even show when i phpinfo();. I think the problem was from the php version it self. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Please tell me that which operating system you used? If window then which version?

you can also try php version 5.3.X it will definitely work.

Comment: I'm using windows 7 home premium. I'll try that.